# UWP app project gets error after addition of .NET Standard 2.0 class library project

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

After I added to my working UWP app a reference to a member in a .NET Standard 2.0 class library, that I added, now when I run it I get this error:

[image]

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>     HResult=0x80070002
>     Message=Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>     Source=CameraFrames
>     StackTrace:
>      at FrameRenderer.ProcessFrame(MediaFrameReference frame) in C:\PRIMARY\WORK\CAMERA READER\Samples\CameraFrames\cs\SOURCE\FrameRenderer.cs:line 393
>      at SDKTemplate.Scenario1_DisplayDepthColorIR.FrameReader_FrameArrived(MediaFrameReader sender, MediaFrameArrivedEventArgs args) in C:\PRIMARY\WORK\CAMERA READER\Samples\CameraFrames\cs\Scenario1_DisplayDepthColorIR.xaml.cs:line 315

Here is the UWP app code that breaks it.  If I remove the "bool aa"... line, it works.

```
        public void ProcessFrame( MediaFrameReference frame)
    {
                       // TEST MULTI-PROJ
                       bool aa = UWP_BRIDGE_DotNet_Standard_ClassLibrary.Class1.flag;
```

Here is the code in the .NET Standard 2.0 class lib...

```
    using System;

namespace UWP_BRIDGE_DotNet_Standard_ClassLibrary
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static bool flag = false;
        public static string buffer = "HELLO";
    }
}
```

I set UWP project properties > Targeting > Target & Min version  both to Windows 10 v 1803 and it still errors.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem when using .NET Standard class library and 16299 SDK as Min/Max target version. And I've checked my class library, which is using .NET Standard.Library 2.0.3. What's your Visual Studio version? Is it possible that your Visual Studio needs to be updated?

Answer (score 0):

May the problem is from .NET framework.

you must target your .NET framework to 4.6.1 at least if you using .NET Core 2.0
Check the table in this link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard